# Essere strumentale a/in/per(?) + verbo/sostantivo

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Ecco le alternative a cui ho pensato, essendo quelle con la `[E]` quelle che mi convincono di più:

> Questa cosa è strumentale nel capire

> Questa cosa è strumentale al capire

> Questa cosa è strumentale a capire `[E]`

> Questa cosa è strumentale per capire `[E]`

Naturalmente potrei cambiare *capire* con *comprensione*,

> Questa cosa è strumentale nella comprensione

> Questa cosa è strumentale alla comprensione `[E]`

> Questa cosa è strumentale per la comprensione

ma il dubbio resta.

Ove mai fosse ritenuto importante (a me non sembra), la frase originaria è la seguente, di mia fattura (quindi "lavori in corso"):

> Emergerà che queste forze sono strumentali alla comprensione del processo di creazione e rigenerazione.

Comment: Non mi sembra che l'aggettivo “strumentale” si usi così, con una preposizione e qualcos'altro. Vedi https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/strumentale, https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/strumentale e Zingarelli (dietro paywall). A parte gli altri sensi del termine, in questo senso si usa in modo assoluto (“organizzare uno sciopero strumentale”). È possibile che tu abbia in mente l'aggettivo inglese _instrumental_, che invece si può effettivamente costruire con _in_?

Comment: Ho appena controllato sul Devoto-Oli e, in effetti, dell'uso di _strumentale_ che ho fatto io non c'è traccia alcuna. È probabile che tu abbia ragione, @DaG, benché ho l'impressione di averlo, almeno, sentito come ho mostrato nella domanda. In effetti, al secondo linke che proponi c'è _fare un uso strumentale del gioco a fini educativi_, che mi sembra vicino all'uso che ne ho forse erroneamente fatto io.

Comment: Giusto, @Enlico, quella frase ci si avvicina, ma la costruzione è un po' diversa. Potrei anche fare un uso avventato, o sperimentale, del gioco a fini educativi, ma non per questo potrei costruire “avventato” o “sperimentale” direttamente con una preposizione.

Comment: Invece l'_instrumental_ ha un uso più simile a quello che per l'italiano è [“mirato” e sinonimi](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/mirato_(Sinonimi-e-Contrari)) o eventualmente “funzionale” (che a me personalmente suona troppo burocratico, ma comunque [secondo il Treccani si può costruire con “a”](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/funzionale1), anche se sembra che ne limitino l'uso all'arredamento e l'architettura).

Comment: Credo di non capire appieno il tuo commento. _Fare un uso strumentale del gioco **ai fini** educativi_ mi sembre logicamente equivalente a _usare il gioco **per** educare_, che in qualche modo mi porta a dire che forse _strumentale_ sarebbe (nell'uso che io credevo corretto) comunque superfluo, in quanto _fare uso del gioco ai/con fini educativi_ sembra comunicare lo stesso significato, e non meno chiaramente. Invece, in _fare un uso avventato/sperimentale del gioco ai fini educativi_ mi sembra che l'uno o l'altro aggettivo vadano a caratterizzare meglio l'_uso_ del gioco.

Comment: Ad ogni modo, forse dovrei solo scegliere _utile a_ e tagliare la testa al toro.

Comment: Per la verità l'uso di 'strumentale alla  comprensione' e simili non mi è affatto nuovo, mi è familiare, e penso che sia corretto. Probabilmente anche qui ci sono differenze di uso, forse in zone dell'Italia, non saprei. Primo esempio che ho trovato in rete https://context.reverso.net/traduzione/italiano-inglese/strumentale+al

Comment: Secondo me va bene 'strumentale' , dipende dal contesto e dal tono del discorso, se è meglio 'utile' o 'strumentale', e da quello che preferisci.Tenendo presente che tra 'utile' e 'strumentale' possono esserci differenti sfumature di significato. Metterei sempre strumentale *al/alla*, non *a*, come se quello dopo fosse un verbo sostantivato.

Comment: Scusa se sono stato poco chiaro, @Enlico, intendevo solo che quell'aggettivo connota l'evento di cui si parla (con vari significati a seconda dell'aggettivo stesso) e non c'entra direttamente con l'eventuale complemento “a fini...” che viene dopo. Nel caso di “strumentale” la connoterebbe come “concepito e attuato non per il suo scopo più immediato, ma per un secondo fine e per un interesse non dichiarato” (Treccani), che forse non era il senso che avevi in mente.

Comment: @BakerStreet: Grazie, ma a me personalmente gli esempi che compaiono in Reverso (di cui tra l'altro non so come vedere la fonte originaria) “puzzano” di calco dall'inglese, anche se sono stati scritti da italiani, tra l'altro perché in italiano “strumentale” non ha il senso di “mirato” etc.: un po' come quando uno dice “triviale” intendendo “banale”, o “quotare” intendendo “citare”.

Comment: Non ho mai visto esempi come dici in Reverso, di traduzioni pedestri dall'inglese, e credo che spesso prendano le frasi da testi italiani, di cui, come dici, è difficile capire le fonti. Continuo a credere che 'strumentale al' vada benissimo, a me è del tutto familiare, se trovo altri esempi non su Reverso te lo dico.

Comment: Strumentale può avere il senso di 'mirato a', funzionale a uno scopo https://dizionarioitaliano.it/strumentale/. , come si dice 'funzionale al' si può dire 'strumentale al'. Io lo scriverei senza problemi, però naturalmente puoi non esserne convinto.

Comment: Ad esempio renatodisa.com/…. . Al massimo può avere un sapore un po' burocratico, ne ho trovati altri simili, di esempi. Se cerchi su Google 'strumentale al perseguimento' ne trovi a pacchi. Ma non è che voglio per forza convincerti, eh? :-)

Comment: @BakerStreet: Si trovano anche mucchi di esempi di “triviale” e “quotare” nei sensi che dicevo... In questo caso mi dà da pensare che i dizionari veri e propri non registrino questo uso di “strumentale”. Ma magari sono all'antica io ed è un uso che si sta diffondendo. :) No, certo nessuno deve convincere nessuno: sono varie fonti e opinioni personali che è utile scambiarsi.